# How to sort a list of custom Objects by using the properties?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to sort a list of custom objects by a property.
Here is what the class for the object looks like:

```
class CloudTodo {
  final String documentId;
  final String userId;
  final String description;
  final String title;
  final bool isChecked;
  final Timestamp? dueDate;

  const CloudTodo({
    required this.dueDate,
    required this.documentId,
    required this.userId,
    required this.description,
    required this.title,
    required this.isChecked,
  });

  CloudTodo.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        userId = snapshot.data()[ownerUserIdFieldName],
        title = snapshot.data()[titleFieldName] as String,
        description = snapshot.data()[descriptionFieldName] as String,
        isChecked = snapshot.data()[isCheckedFieldName] as bool,
        dueDate = snapshot.data()[dueDateFieldName];
}
```

The property I want to sort by is the `dueDate` variable and I will convert the `Timestamp` to `DateTime` in order to compare.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
listOfCustomObjects.sort((a, b) => a.dueDate.compareTo(b.dueDate));
```